# Restructure data frame- gather years in one column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a big data frame looking like this:

| location | type | 2005 |  |  | 2006 |  |  | 2007 |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | Sentenced | Female | College | Sentenced | Female | College | Sentenced | Female | College |
| Paris | 1 | Yes | No | Yes | No | No | Yes | No | Yes | No |
| Paris | 2 | No | No | No | Yes | No | Yes | No | No | Yes |
| Paris | 3 | No | Yes | No | Yes | No | Yes | Yes | No | Yes |
| Madrid | 1 | Yes | No | No | No | Yes | No | No | Yes | No |
| Madrid | 2 | No | Yes | No | No | Yes | No | Yes | No | Yes |
| Miami | 1 | Yes | No | Yes | Yes | No | Yes | Yes | No | Yes |

And I want to restructure it, to look like this:

| year | location | Type | Sentenced | Female | College |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2005 | Paris | 1 | Yes | No | Yes |
| 2005 | Paris | 2 | Yes | No | Yes |
| 2005 | Paris | 3 | Yes | No | Yes |
| 2005 | Madrid | 1 | Yes | No | Yes |
| 2005 | Madrid | 2 | Yes | No | Yes |
| 2005 | Miami | 1 | Yes | No | Yes |
| 2006 | Paris | 1 | Yes | No | Yes |
| 2006 | Paris | 2 | Yes | No | Yes |
| 2006 | Paris | 3 | Yes | No | Yes |
| 2006 | Madrid | 1 | Yes | No | Yes |
| 2006 | Madrid | 2 | Yes | No | Yes |
| 2006 | Miami | 3 | Yes | No | Yes |

Please don´t pay attention to the internal validity of the two tables. It´s just for vizualization.

I tried the gather function in R, but failed, because it seems to require only one varaible per year and not three ( in my case: sentenced, female, college).

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  In particular, use `dput()` to post your data, not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried reproducing your example :

```
test <- structure(list(location = c(NA, "Paris", "Paris", "Paris", "Madrid", 
"Madrid", "Miami"), type = c(NA, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1), `2005...3` = c("Sentenced", 
"Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes"), `2005...4` = c("Female", 
"No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No"), `2005...5` = c("College", 
"Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes"), `2006...6` = c("Sentenced", 
"No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes"), `2006...7` = c("Female", 
"No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No"), `2006...8` = c("College", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes"), `2007...9` = c("Sentenced", 
"No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes"), `2007...10` = c("Female", 
"Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No"), `2007...11` = c("College", 
"No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes")), row.names = c(NA, -7L
 ), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

You basically needed to merge the top two rows to form a header and use the following code

```
names(test) <- paste(names(test),test[1,],sep = "_") 
test <- test[-1,]

test <- gather(test,"key","value",3:11)
test <- test %>% separate(key,c("Year","Key"),"_")      
test <- test %>% separate(Year,c("Year","Garbage"),"[.]")
test <- test %>% select(-Garbage)
test <- test %>% spread(Key,value)
```